# Hover effect is around a block not the image

Tags: html, css

[image: 1]

How can I make the hover effect around the image itself, not the block?

```css
.me {
    display:inline-flex;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 100px;   
}

.me img:hover {
    box-shadow:
    0 0 4px #a9a,
    0 0 7px #a8a,
    0 0 15px #a7a,
    0 0 20px #a6a,
    0 0 30px #a5a,
    0 0 40px #5271ff,
    0 0 50px #5271ff,
    0 0 60px #5271ff;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post enough code so we can run things for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example And what do you mean by 'the image itself'?

Comment: can you give the image of this, the image you linked is the one with the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np4kC.png

Comment: ```.me {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    display:inline-flex;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: -10px;
    right: 100px;   
}```

Comment: can you explain what you mean, pls ? Do you want that the shadow to be following the png (and not the square) or the :hover be readed only inside the image, and not in the transparent place

Comment: if you want the shadow be following the border of the png (so not the square border) use `filter: drop-shadow();` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.